# R: Combine or compare several lists with different lengths

Tags: r, xml

I am working with several XML files that I want to compare, each containing about 200-300 different 'xml:ids'. Let's say there are three files contain the following xml:ids:

**file1.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<div>
<p xml:id= "F23_1b">1</p>
<p xml:id= "F54_34a">3</p>
</div>
```

**file2.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<div>
<p xml:id= "F23_1b">7</p>
<p xml:id= "F54_34a">8</p>
<p xml:id= "F54_63d">12</p>
</div>
```

**file3.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<div>
<p xml:id= "F143_32a">5</p>
<p xml:id= "F175_23c">6</p>
<p xml:id= "F95_1a">14</p>
<p xml:id= "F89_9d">15</p>
</div>
```

Now my goal is to compare these different files concerning a) the present xml:ids and b) their respective values (see table below). I started by using R's XML package / XPath to create a list for each file:

```
file1 <- xmlTreeParse("file1.xml", useInternalNodes = T)
a <- xpathSApply(file1, "//*[@xml:id]", xmlGetAttr, "xml:id")

file2 <- xmlTreeParse("file1.xml", useInternalNodes = T)
a <- xpathSApply(file1, "//*[@xml:id]", xmlGetAttr, "xml:id")

file3 <- xmlTreeParse("file1.xml", useInternalNodes = T)
a <- xpathSApply(file1, "//*[@xml:id]", xmlGetAttr, "xml:id")
```

Now in a second step, I'd like to combine the results in one data frame but – and this is my main problem – the lists don't share the same length. At first I thought that I might just look for the longest list and add 'empty values' for xml:ids that are present in it but not in the shorter ones but I quickly realized that this approach would ignore ids which do only exist in the shorter lists.

In the end, I'd love to have a data frame that can easily be exported (to .csv), looking similar to this table:

```
|------------||-----------||-----------||-----------|
|  xml:ids   ||   file1   ||   file2   ||   file3   |
|------------||-----------||-----------||-----------|
|------------||-----------||-----------||-----------|
|  F23_1b    ||     1     ||     7     ||    NULL   |
|------------||-----------||-----------||-----------|
|  F54_34a   ||     3     ||     8     ||    NULL   |
|------------||-----------||-----------||-----------|
|  F54_63d   ||   NULL    ||    12     ||    NULL   |
|------------||-----------||-----------||-----------|
|  F143_32a  ||   NULL    ||    NULL   ||     5     |
|------------||-----------||-----------||-----------|
|  F175_23c  ||   NULL    ||    NULL   ||     6     |
|------------||-----------||-----------||-----------|
|  F95_1a    ||   NULL    ||    NULL   ||     14    |
|------------||-----------||-----------||-----------|
|  F89_9d    ||   NULL    ||    NULL   ||     15    |
|------------||-----------||-----------||-----------|
```

Do you have any suggestions concerning my problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use xml2 and purrr, it might look something like

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(xml2) 


xml_data <- sprintf('file%s.xml', 1:3) %>%    # make filepaths
    map_df(~read_xml(.x) %>%    # iterate over filenames; read xml
               xml_find_all('//p') %>%    # select p nodes
               map_df(function(.y) {   # iterate over nodes and combine to data frame of...
                   list(file = basename(.x),    # the filename, 
                        id = xml_attr(.y, 'id'),    # the id attribute, and
                        value = as.integer(xml_text(.y)))    # the node value.
               }))

xml_data
#> # A tibble: 9 x 3
#>   file      id       value
#>   <chr>     <chr>    <int>
#> 1 file1.xml F23_1b       1
#> 2 file1.xml F54_34a      3
#> 3 file2.xml F23_1b       7
#> 4 file2.xml F54_34a      8
#> 5 file2.xml F54_63d     12
#> 6 file3.xml F143_32a     5
#> 7 file3.xml F175_23c     6
#> 8 file3.xml F95_1a      14
#> 9 file3.xml F89_9d      15
```

If you really want to spread it to wide form, from here it's pretty typical:

```r
xml_data %>% 
    mutate(file = sub('.xml$', '', file)) %>% 
    spread(file, value)
#> # A tibble: 7 x 4
#>   id       file1 file2 file3
#>   <chr>    <int> <int> <int>
#> 1 F143_32a    NA    NA     5
#> 2 F175_23c    NA    NA     6
#> 3 F23_1b       1     7    NA
#> 4 F54_34a      3     8    NA
#> 5 F54_63d     NA    12    NA
#> 6 F89_9d      NA    NA    15
#> 7 F95_1a      NA    NA    14
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works! 
Now I'm trying to understand what you did with **map_df** but I can't figure it out on my own. I read the documentation but I don't get the structure of your function, especially the use of **.x** and **.y** (I'm obviously new to programming and R). Can you help me there?

Comment: `purrr::map` is a version of `lapply` that similarly iterates an anonymous function over a vector or list, but which accepts a function notation where you can just type `~` instead of `function(.x)`, and the variable will be called `.x`. For the inner `map`, I used an explicit function, as I wanted a different variable name to avoid confusion. The `_df` part means `map` will take the results and call `dplyr::bind_rows` on them to coerce them into a data frame. Thus, the outer call iterates over files and combines to a single data frame, the inner over `p` nodes and to a data frame per file.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using `xml2` and `dplyr::full_join`:

```
 # Read XML files
 library(xml2);
 fn <- paste0("file", 1:3, ".xml");
 files <- lapply(fn, read_xml);

 # Extract node attributes and values, store as data.frame
 lst <- lapply(files, function(x)
     cbind.data.frame(
         id = xml_attr(xml_children(x), "id"),
         val = as.numeric(xml_text(xml_children(x))),
         stringsAsFactors = F))

 # Outer full join on all data.frame's in list
 df <- Reduce(function(x, y) dplyr::full_join(x, y, by = "id"), lst)
 colnames(df)[2:ncol(df)] <- fn;
 df;
 #        id file1.xml file2.xml file3.xml
 #1   F23_1b         1         7        NA
 #2  F54_34a         3         8        NA
 #3  F54_63d        NA        12        NA
 #4 F143_32a        NA        NA         5
 #5 F175_23c        NA        NA         6
 #6   F95_1a        NA        NA        14
 #7   F89_9d        NA        NA        15
```

Explanation: Read XML files with `xml2::read_xml`; extract node attributes and values with `xml_attr` and `xml_text`, respectively, and store as `list` of `data.frame`s; perform full outer join on `data.frame`s in `list`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how flexible you are in your choice of technology, but here is a solution in XSLT 3.0

```
<xsl:variable name="doc1" select="doc('file1.xml')"/>
<xsl:variable name="doc2" select="doc('file2.xml')"/>
<xsl:variable name="doc3" select="doc('file3.xml')"/>
<xsl:merge>
  <xsl:merge-source for-each-source="($doc1, $doc2, doc3)" select=".//p[@xml:id]">
    <xsl:merge-key select="@xml:id" sort-before-merge="yes"/>
  </xsl:merge-source>
  <xsl:merge-action>
    <tr>
      <td>{current-merge-key()}</td>
      <xsl:for-each select="($doc1, $doc2, doc3)">
         <td>{(current-merge-group()[(/) is current()], 'NA')[1]}</td>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </tr>
  </xsl:merge-action>
</xsl:merge>
```

Not tested. Easily generalised to N input documents.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I could switch to XSLT but I thought that it might be easier to stick to XPath (which I already used occasionally), especially since I'm rather new to programming, R, and X technologies. I know that I have a long way to go...